# Panel data: cohort, track id over time

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby

Suppose i have the following dataframe corresponding to panel data of firms. The variable `entry` specify whenever the firms entry to the market, upon this variable I want to create a cohort (track the firm over time). There is any way to perform such code? (basically the variable `cohort` should specify the year whenever `entry = 1`

From this dataframe

```
id  year  entry  
 1  2009    0     
 1  2012    1     
 1  2013    0     
 1  2014    0     
 2  2010    1     
 2  2011    0    
 2  2012    0     
 3  2007    0    
 3  2008    0     
 3  2012    1     
 3  2013    0
```

i need to pass something like this

```
id  year  entry  cohort
 1  2009    0     NaN
 1  2012    1     2012
 1  2013    0     2012
 1  2014    0     2012
 2  2010    1     2010
 2  2011    0     2010
 2  2012    0     2010
 3  2007    0     NaN
 3  2008    0     NaN
 3  2012    1     2012
 3  2013    0     2012
```

Thank you very much, and sorry my english, is not native english (i am practicing as equal as python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the `year` where `entry` is equal to one:

```
df.year.where(df.entry == 1)
#0        NaN
#1     2012.0
#2        NaN
#3        NaN
#4     2010.0
#5        NaN
#6        NaN
#7        NaN
#8        NaN
#9     2012.0
#10       NaN
#Name: year, dtype: float64
```

Then use `groupby + ffill`:

```
df["cohort"] = df.year.where(df.entry == 1).groupby(df.id).ffill()

df
#    id  year  entry  cohort
#0    1  2009      0     NaN
#1    1  2012      1  2012.0
#2    1  2013      0  2012.0
#3    1  2014      0  2012.0
#4    2  2010      1  2010.0
#5    2  2011      0  2010.0
#6    2  2012      0  2010.0
#7    3  2007      0     NaN
#8    3  2008      0     NaN
#9    3  2012      1  2012.0
#10   3  2013      0  2012.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much. May i ask you another question, in the case i have the same first df of my question with one new column `jobs`. So i want to calculate the mean of jobs whenever a firm is recently born (entry==1), do you know how to resolve it? @Psidom

Comment: Not sure how your data looks like and what your desired result be. But possibly `df.jobs.groupby([df.id, df.entry.cumsum()]).mean()`?

Comment: Or calculate mean of jobs per id only after entry == 1. `df[df.entry.groupby(df.id).cumsum() != 0].groupby('id').jobs.mean()`.

Comment: i posted my doubt at "Panel data: mean, groupby and with a condition" so as to clarify what i mean

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

```
df['cphort']=df.year.mask(df.entry==0).groupby(df.id).ffill()
df
Out[202]: 
    id  year  entry  cphort
0    1  2009      0     NaN
1    1  2012      1  2012.0
2    1  2013      0  2012.0
3    1  2014      0  2012.0
4    2  2010      1  2010.0
5    2  2011      0  2010.0
6    2  2012      0  2010.0
7    3  2007      0     NaN
8    3  2008      0     NaN
9    3  2012      1  2012.0
10   3  2013      0  2012.0
```